# Issue accessing free list nodes by memory address in pool allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

I'm attempting to write a simple pool allocator for allocation and deallocation in c++ as part of a uni course task. We were given a reference to to git-user floooh's oryol engine, https://github.com/floooh/oryol/blob/master/code/Modules/Core/Memory/poolAllocator.h, hence I try to do something similar by splitting the pool into puddles that are allocated when needed. Starting with one and then incrementing as memory demands increase.

Each puddle in my case maintains its own free list of nodes and I fail already in creating the first puddle: I get segmentation fault when I try to access node struct data members. Below is my pool allocator class description along with constructor and function for adding a puddle. I commented in caps lock "SEGMENTATION FAULT" in allocNewPuddle() where it fails, line 10 in that function.

Class description:

```
template<class T> class memAllocator {
public:
  memAllocator();
  ~memAllocator();

  struct Puddle;

  struct mNode {
    mNode* nextN;
    mNode* prevN;
    uint puddle;
  };

  struct Puddle {
    mNode* headN_free;
    mNode* headN_occ;
  };

  uint numPuddles;
  static const uint nodesInPuddle = 512;
  static const uint maxPuddles = 512;
  Puddle* puddles[maxPuddles];

  uint nodeSize;
  uint elemSize;
  uint puddleStructSize;

  void allocNewPuddle();
  void* allocate();
  void deallocate(void* obj);
  void* findNextFreeNode();
  template<typename... ARGS> T* create(ARGS&&... args);
  void destroy(T* obj);

};
```

Constructor:

```
template<class T>
memAllocator<T>::memAllocator() // creates instance of allocator starting with one puddle allocated
{
  this->numPuddles = 0;
  this->nodeSize = sizeof(mNode);
  this->elemSize = nodeSize + sizeof(T);
  this->puddleStructSize = sizeof(Puddle);

  allocNewPuddle();
}
```

Add a new puddle:

```
template<class T>
void memAllocator<T>::allocNewPuddle() // allocates a new puddle
{
  // allocate memory for one puddle
  assert(numPuddles < maxPuddles);
  Puddle* newPuddle = (Puddle*) malloc(puddleStructSize + nodesInPuddle * elemSize);

  // allocate nodes in free list pointed to by puddle struct
  newPuddle->headN_free = (mNode*) (newPuddle + puddleStructSize + (nodesInPuddle-1)*elemSize);
  for (int i = nodesInPuddle-2; i >= 0; i--) {
    mNode* curNode = (mNode*) (newPuddle + puddleStructSize + i*elemSize);
    // Fails here when attempting to access mNode struct members
    curNode->puddle = numPuddles; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE ON FIRST ITERATION
    curNode->prevN = nullptr;
    curNode->nextN = newPuddle->headN_free;
    curNode->nextN->prevN = curNode;
    newPuddle->headN_free = curNode;
  }
  newPuddle->headN_occ = nullptr;
  puddles[numPuddles] = newPuddle;
  numPuddles++;
}
```

Here is my main.cc:

```
#include "memAllocator.h"
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
  Test();
  ~Test();
  int arr[5];
};

Test::Test() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     this->arr[i] = i;
  }
}

Test::~Test() {
  std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  memAllocator<Test> memPool = memAllocator<Test> ();
  Test* test = memPool.create();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << test->arr[i] << std::endl;
  }
  memPool.destroy(test);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << test->arr[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

My guess is that I am doing something horribly naïve with c++ pointers, but from what I know the above should work. If not then I look forward to a good scolding.

Oh, and as you can see I'm not bothering to align memory since it is a small assignment, and as I understand this is not essential for it to work it only makes it faster, but is it possible this can cause wrong memory to be read and written to as more is demanded?

Comment: And debugging that revealed **which** line as the culprit, please? I would debug it myself, but you haven't  provided a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, made it clearer now. Will edit in a short main that produces the issue. Thanks for telling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect address calculation in line

```
mNode* curNode = (mNode*) (newPuddle + puddleStructSize + i*elemSize);
```

**newPuddle** is Puddle pointer, but you trying to add bytes. Thus you have new address far beyond end of allocated memory buffer. So you must add explicit cast to byte pointer (char, uint8_t etc)

```
mNode* curNode = (mNode*) ((char*)newPuddle + puddleStructSize + i*elemSize);
```

You must fix this line too

```
newPuddle->headN_free = (mNode*) (newPuddle + puddleStructSize + (nodesInPuddle-1)*elemSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it fixed the problem, I had similar issue in other places in code because I didn't know the above. So before the fix I was in fact incrementing a Puddle pointer for every byte I added?